# How to Date deduction with Python?

Tags: python, xml, odoo

here shows **date of birth** field in my openerp model

```
'date_of_birth': fields.date('Date of Birth'),
```

need to change its default date to 25years earlier.because its easier to user to pick year.
( in openerp jquery default load current 20years in list and user have to get some time to select earlier year ).

for ex :

```
_defaults = {
'date_of_birth':fields.date.context_today - 25years
```

please advice me to implement this issue (if its with python function seems good for my requirement )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the [dateutil module](http://labix.org/python-dateutil) - you'll have to install it. It makes this sort of calculation easy.

```
>>> import datetime
... from dateutil import relativedelta
... 
... today = datetime.date.today()
... past = today + relativedelta.relativedelta(years=-25)
... print(today, past, sep='\t')
2013-05-05  1988-05-05
```

Comment: thanks Dear Bo102010
now need it to return in OpenERP (ver 7) format :-)

Answer (score 1):

If your 'Date of birth' is a string, then you can use [enter link description here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.strptime)strptime to convert it into a datetime object.
With that object, it is much easier to substract 25 years using the [timedelta](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects) module

You can't substract 25 years straight away, you have to count how many days manually.

But in the end, it will look like this:

```
import datetime

my_date = datetime.datetime.strptime('1 Feb 2013', '%d %b %Y')  # converts the date 1 Feb 2013 into a datetime object
new_date = my_date - datetime.timedelta(days=36000)  # Substracts 36000 days
print(new_date.strftime('%d %b %y'))  # prints: '11 Jul 1914'
```

Answer (score 0):

now its works with this code

```
def _dob(self, cr, uid, context=None):
    today = datetime.date.today()
    past = today + relativedelta.relativedelta(years= -25)
    return past.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

thanks all answers